# How to scroll to a component after it's shown on the page on React?

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

I need to scroll to the component after it gets rendered to the page (I am using [React scroll to component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-to-component)). The component itself is not shown by default (the component will be rendered when `example_shown` is `true`). Something like this:

```
{props.example_shown && (
    <ExtraComponent />
)}
```

and inside the `ExtraComponent`, I give `ref={(section) => { this.ExtraComponent = section }}`.
I tried to call `scrollToComponent` inside `componentDidMount()` but `this.ExtraComponent` returns to `null`. How can I scroll to position? Ideally `componentDidMount()` should work right? I have been reading about the life cycle and couldn't solve it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOUND THE ANSWER!

```
componentDidMount() {
    var elementWhereIwantToScrollTo = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
    scrollToComponent(elementWhereIwantToScrollTo, { offset: 0, align: 'middle', duration: 500, ease: 'inCirc' })
}
```

then on the render, I specify:

```
<CardBox
   ref={(section) => { this.elementWhereIwantToScrollTo = section }}
>
```

Comment: scrollToComponent is not defined, you must install https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-to-component and `import scrollToComponent from 'react-scroll-to-component'`